# How to understand the time in Gnuradio?

Tags: gnuradio

I have the following questions:

1. I have set the initial phase of the signal source to 0, But I can barely capture the waveform with an initial phase of 0 even if I stop the time sink ASAP. why?
2. After I stop time sink, did the signal source continues to output but the data stream is discarded? Or did the source stop sending data?
3. I've read the official tutorials on "python block", I presume that the signal source sends a certain length of data stream each time. Is there a global time variable in every two consecutive strems? If so how do I use it in a python block? If not, how does signal source ensure the phase consistency between the data streams?

Thanks！

I actually want to implement a GPS PRN generator block using python block, but until I figure out the questions above, it seems I can't accomplish this task.

[image]

Comment: "I've watched the tutorial on…" **which** tutorial? We (as in: the GNU Radio project) don't have "official" video tutorials, we do have official guided text tutorials, which address a lot of your questions, on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org

Comment: (your second question by the way is excellent and I don't think we've documented that anywhere!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your reply. I may have misused the word "watch" because English is not my native language. I have read the official Beginner Tutorials from [link](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Tutorials). Can you provide me with more specific guidelines? For example, which part of the official tutorial has a description of questions 1 and 3? Much appreciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly, should I use `nitems_written(which_output)` to calculate the "time" in my question? Thanks. @MarcusMüller

Comment: Welcome to the amateur radio stack!  You've really asked three questions here.  It would be best if you could either distill down to a single question or post separate questions.